# Passing pointers array to function GTK related

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, gtk

I have following array:

```
GtkWidget*GtkEntrys[3];
```

It's being created,etc and now I want to pass it function so I do:

```
g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(Buttons[0]),"clicked",G_CALLBACK(CreateProfile),EntryBoxes);

void CreateProfile(GtkWidget* widget, gpointer**data)
{
    if (gtk_entry_get_text_length(GTK_ENTRY(data[0]))== 0) std::cout << "Empty" << std::endl;
}
```

But I'm getting error: `GTK_IS_ENTRY FAILED`

Answer (score 1):

I presume in

```
 g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(Buttons[0]),"clicked",G_CALLBACK(CreateProfile),EntryBoxes);
```

`EntryBoxes` actually is `GtkEntrys` defined before. What you pass there is not a pointer to the array, but a pointer to the first array element. So you must cast the `gpointer` to an pointer to such an element, i.e. to a `GtkEntry*` (not a `GtkEntry**`)

```
void CreateProfile(GtkWidget* widget, gpointer data) {
    GtkEntry* entries = (GtkEntry*) data;
    if (gtk_entry_get_text_length(GTK_ENTRY(entries[0]))== 0)
        do_something();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void CreateProfile(GtkWidget* widget, gpointer data) {
    GtkEntry** entries = (GtkEntry**) data;
    if (gtk_entry_get_text_length(GTK_ENTRY(entries[0]))== 0) do_something();
}
```

second argument of callback should be gpoitner.